# Using fstream tellg to read a portion of the stream till the end

Tags: c++, buffer, fstream

I have this simple code that needs to get a chunk of a large log file that is being written into. At some point it stores the current location returned from 
streampos start = istream::tellg();
method.
Later on the code has to read from the stream a buffer from the start till the end. The code is approximately like this:

```
streampos start = my_stream.tellg();

... // do some stuff with logging

streampos end = my_stream.tellg();
const streamsize size_to_read = (end - start);
char *buf = new char[size_to_read];

lock (m_logReadLock);
{
    my_stream.flush();
    my_stream.seekg(start);
    my_stream.read(buf, size_to_read);
    size_read = my_stream->gcount();
}
unlock (m_logReadLock);
```

The effect that I'm observing is that **size_read** is *smaller* than **size_to_read** and the stream has its eof flag set. Shouldn't the end pointer specify exactly where the stream ends and read() method return that exact amount of data?
It is fine, I can work round it by checking the eof flag. 
However, can anyone provide the explanation for this effect?

Thanks.

Comment: read() doesn't guarantee to read the size you give it.

Comment: In understand that.
The question is why read() reads less than (end - start) and reaches the end of the stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_thread/thread/709cde3942e64d6c#

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be calling `gcount` on `stream_loc` instead of `my_stream`.

Comment: Is using `begin_stream_pos`, `begin`, and `start` for the same thing another copy paste error?